# How do I use regular expression to extract a value with specific unit and sum up

Tags: regex, excel, vba

How do I use a regular expression to extract a value with specific unit and sum up.

Input at A1, output at A2

I only want to add the value with mm
[image: I only want to add the value with mm]

I tried this code provided from stackoverflow, and I add "?mm" after the `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`but there is an error message.

```
Function sumNums(str As String) As Double
Dim n As Long
Static rgx As Object, cmat As Object

If rgx Is Nothing Then
    Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
End If

With rgx
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?mm"
    If .test(str) Then
        Set cmat = .Execute(str)
        For n = 0 To cmat.Count - 1
            sumNums = sumNums + CDbl(cmat.Item(n))
        Next n
    End If
End With
End Function
```

Comment: The Regular Expression looks right. Can you please post the error message?

Comment: @4ndy it just shows up #Value! at A2

Comment: Have you added a reference to Regular Expressions? [Have a look at the accepted answer under this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops).

Comment: @4ndy Hi, it works for me for this code "(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)" ---> it will sum up all the number no matter what. but it didnt work at this code "(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?mm". it will show up #Value! .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strings being parsed by the regex are just that; strings. The original UDF uses CDbl to convert these to true numbers and it is successful because they are only numbers. To convert a string-number with a trailing suffix, use Val.

Try this simple regex based UDF.

```
Option Explicit


Function sumMMnums(str As String) As Double
    Dim n As Long
    Static rgx As Object, cmat As Object

    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    End If

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "(\-?\d*\.?\d+)mm"
        If .test(str) Then
            Set cmat = .Execute(str)
            For n = 0 To cmat.Count - 1
                sumMMnums = sumMMnums + Val(cmat.Item(n))
            Next n
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Finally... thanks Jeeped. Because you answered the same question from me before.. that's why....